# Most of my photos have uploaded to Google photos, but not by me

Tags: macos, google-photos

How can it be that most of my photo archive has uploaded to Google photos without me every knowing it? I have no idea how they got there, and no idea how to stop this from happening again. If it helps, I use a MacBook Pro and I keep all my photos in the Photos app (formerly iPhoto). I really need to know what is going on here, as it frightens me to think that personal family images might be floating around the internet.

Answer (score 2):

Google doesn't share your photos with the web automatically.  It may have upload them, but they are not automatically shared with anyone.  It maybe that you, or another member of the household installed Google Photo backup.  Google Photo backup could have come bundled with another product you installed.

**You control what is shared and what is not.**

As a prolific google photo user, I have 30,000 pictures, and not a single one was shared without **me** clicking the **share** button.

For me, it provides a convenient way of backing up my photos in case of fire,flood, theft, hardware failure, and etc.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that. You are right, it does appear that none of the photos are public. However, it still frightens me that this happened. I have no idea how. I do not use google photo backup, I always have that feature switched off on my mobile devices, and many of the photos that have been backed up have never been on a mobile device anyway. So this has totally happened on my macbook. I've searched the system, checked all settings, I cannot find an answer. I'm guessing that there is a setting somewhere that I have messed up at some time, but I cannot find it.

Comment: @DavidA.Moody   Do you have any other google products besides chrome?  Maybe picasa?  You need to look at all the software on your computer capable of editing/organzing pictures, and any file management software you have on there and see if they have google integration.  Since, I don't know what software you have installed, I can only make educated guesses maybe you have google drive installed locally.